# Right way for handling a java web application startup error

Tags: java, servlets, error-handling, war

I'm currently writing a java web application that performs specific checks at startup. Example, checking that the configuration file exists and defines all the required setting variables.

I placed the checking code inside the a subclass of the `ServletContextListener` class and registered the ServletContextListener subclass inside web.xml using:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.bloxware.lls3.MainContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In the overridden contextInitialized() method I wrote code that checks the configuration file is in place and contains valid values.

**If an error takes place at startup, I want to log this error and inform the web user in a suitable manner.**

I need help **on how to move forward from here**:

1. Am I reading the configuration file parameters in the correct place (inside the ServletContextListener.contextInitialized(..) method )?
2. How would I handle showing an error page to the user once this takes place (eg. shall I add code to each servlet and jsp page to check a global flag, or can I do that in a smarter way, possibly ServletRequestListener.requestInitialized(..))?
3. I need a way that if the user fixes the configuration file, refreshing the page is sufficient and there is no need to restart the web application.

Answer (score 2):

I can respect the goal of having a dynamic configuration that checks itself, but realistically I wouldn't suggest going that route.

For the most part (caveats later) when a web application starts up, it either is configured correctly or it isn't. If the application is mis-configured, it simply won't work. For example, when applications start, many will connect to a database. If they connection string is wrong, there is never going to be a good user experience. This should be handled at startup, and startup *only*. The web application should NOT start, if it knows that it cannot function. Spattering code through your entire application to deal with that isn't the way to go.

The idea of checking this on context initialization is fine. But, it should be perfectly willing to throw a detailed and logged exception on the spot so that an administrator (not a user!) can deal with the issue and restart the app.

As for dynamic configurations that update without a restart. This is fine for adjusting non-critical parameters, such as timeout lengths, logging levels, or pool settings. These should only be things that don't bring the app to an immediate halt if they are incorrect. The hostname of your DB connection (for example) isn't one of these things.

In my experience, none of these things is really worth the effort to deal with all the side issues induced by dynamic reloading of configurations. I'd go with just checking things at startup and halting immediately if there is a fatal issue.

EDIT: Side note - Checking that your configuration file is in place and contains all the necessary settings is something that should probably be done in testing, not at application startup time. You can do this as a simple unit test against the file itself.

Comment: What happens if the administrator changed the configuration file and mistyped the database password, database username, or other configuration parameters. If this case takes place, I dont want the web application to allow access to its jsp pages and servlets, instead I want it at least to forward to an error page that would say "An error took place, please consult the administrator". At this point, the administrator can be contacted and he can easily check the log file quickly.

Comment: You said: "The web application should NOT start, if it knows that it cannot function.". Question: How can an application NOT start. What approach should I use so that it does not start, meaning, the serlvets and JSPs become no longer accessible.  Currently, an error gets thrown, but the pages are accessible, I dont like this behavior.

Comment: "Checking that your configuration file is in place and contains all the necessary settings is something that should probably be done in testing, not at application startup time." --> When building a product, a configuration file is part of user input, and should be validated. If the administrator enters wrong values in the configuration file, it should gracefully fail with an indication on the user interface. I cant rely on a unit test for that.

Comment: "Spattering code through your entire application to deal with that isn't the way to go." -> Response: Global status of the application can be checked using a Filter, all code in one place, no need to spatter code across all servlets and JSPs.

Comment: #1 The app config shouldn't be changed willy-nilly. If the admin messes up, hopefully a test would tell them before it hits production. Even if it doesn't, they should be informed by the application startup and monitoring, NOT by the end users. If it got to the end user before the admin, something is wrong. #2 If you throw a servlet exception during init, the web app will fail to start. It will stop in it's tracks. This is how you know you have a misconfiguration. That's better than exposing it to your users.

Comment: #3 We differ on. I believe that you can test configuration before bundling the app, deploying it to production, and starting it. Make it part of the script that builds the WAR file. Don't build the WAR file if non-optional configuration parameters are missing. #4 Yes, you can put that in a filter. That isn't what you said in your original post though.  You said "... shall I add code to each servlet and jsp page to check a global flag ..." That would be the definition of spattering to me.

Comment: Realistically, if you disagree with every single point I made, just ignore the answer or mark it down. This isn't an argument. You asked for input and I provided my opinion. Take it for what's it's worth. You paid nothing :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I really find your advice useful and pragmatic. Thats why I up voted. However, I'm trying to find a bullet proof way in handling startup errors since I'm building a commercial product that will deployed at many client sites. I was searching for advice possibly involving custom error pages, <error-page> tags or a manual mechanism for startup error management. Thanks.